# Passing a row type dynamically to jsonb_populate_recordset

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, rowtype

I'm working on some code to unwind data packed into a JSONB with a regular format for passthrough to another system.

-- Postgres 11.4.
-- The format of the JSON is knowable in advance, it's specified in the record.
-- I've got a custom type for the JSON format defined.

Here's the stripped down passthrough table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.domo_passthrough (
    id           uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT extensions.gen_random_uuid (),
    type_name    text NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    report_data  jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',

CONSTRAINT domo_passthrough_id_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The `report_data` field holds the packed data, the `type_name` field includes the name of the format, like this one:

```
create type data.table_stats_type as (
    table_name text, 
    record_count integer,
    table_number integer)
```

This code works properly to unpack the data into the three columns defined in the type:

```
select expanded_data.*
  from domo_passthrough,
       jsonb_populate_recordset(null::table_stats_type, report_data) as expanded_data;
```

What I'd like to do, if possible, is to pass in the type_name as an argument to `jsonb_populate_recordset`:

```
select expanded_data.*
  from domo_passthrough,
       jsonb_populate_recordset(null::type_name, report_data) as expanded_data;
```

This does *not* work as `null::type_name` returns an error:

```
ERROR:  type "type_name" does not exist
LINE 3:        jsonb_populate_recordset(null::type_name, report_data..
```

Fair. The type_name is a text, not a literal. I'm hoping that there is a tidy way to do what I'm after. (I understand that it's on me at that point to not screw up the type name assignments in the data.) Possibilities:

-- Some kind of `::casting` operation, but I can't figure out what type I'd use between `null::` and `type_name`. I've found the `pg_typeof` function, but don't see a way to apply it to build in code.

-- Dynamic SQL in a function. This seems like it should be possible, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

-- Some other feature or option I'm unaware of.

## RETURN SETOF Function?

Thanks for the comment, I figured I'd try writing a function...and I got stumped. It's always tricky to get dynamic results out of SQL. I'm not complaining about that...but this is one time I'd like to have a generalized tool. It *sounds like* `RETURN SETOF RECORD` ought to work, but I haven't succeeded. I've look through a fair few threads and the docs, but I'm still stumped. Here's a PG/pgSQL function as I couldn't get the pure SQL version to work:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS api.domo_passthrough_expand (text, jsonb);
CREATE FUNCTION api.domo_passthrough_expand(type_name text, packed_data jsonb) 
    RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT
   'select *
      from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::%1$I, %2$I) as expanded_data;',
           type_name,
           packed_data;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER FUNCTION api.domo_passthrough_expand(text, jsonb) OWNER TO user_bender;

select expanded.* 

  from domo_passthrough,
        domo_passthrough_expand(domo_passthrough.type_name,domo_passthrough.report_data)

ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 4:      domo_passthrough_expand(domo_passthrough.type_name,domo...
```

Is there a way to do my expansion generically with the help of a function? If there isn't, I can approach things another way, but I'd prefer to have it all Postgres-side.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without dynamic SQL, since the exact type must be known beforehand to be able to expand the `.*` into column names

Comment: I sat down to try out a function...and failed. I'm not clear if it's possible in Postgres. I've updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: `domo_passthrough_expand` still returns a record, so you have exactly the same problem on that call.

Comment: When all is said and done, I'm thinking that I'm better off building a view. I won't have some enormous collection of different types, and I can write a code generator to inspect a JSON sample and generate a view to match. The view code itself is pretty clear, so that's another advantage. Glad of the help trying to do it with a function, I learned something in the process.